# Calling Oracle stored procedure with DATE input doesn't set the HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures, jdbc

I'm trying to call an Oracle stored procedure in a Java EE web application (java) using Spring 'CallableStatementCreator'. One of the inputs for the stored procedure is a DATE.

My attributeValue is a java.util.date and it correctly holds both DD-MM-YYYY and HH:MM:SS.
When using the following code:

```
callableStmt.setTime(6, new java.sql.Time(attributeValue.getTime()));
```

The result is the column in the DB (the stored procedure ultimately writes in the DB) is set to 1970-01-01 and the correct HH:MM:SS I pass as input. This worked in a previous version of my application (where I used JDBC lib 10.x.x.x)

If I use

```
callableStmt.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(attributeValue.getTime()));
```

The DD-MM-YYYY is set correctly but the hour is set to 00:00:00.

So, what's the correct way to call and pass the attribute to this stored procedure? Also, any debug tips?

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Oracle JDBD lib: ojdbc6-11.2.0.3

Comment: Oracle made a change to this in ojdbc6.jar when moving from Oracle 10 to Oracle 11.  Prior to this setTime set the date and time which was a bug I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
callableStmt.setTimestamp(6, new java.sql.Timestamp(attributeValue.getTime()));
```

Didn't work in my case where I have a stored procedure overloaded where the only difference between my 3 functions is this last parameter: VARCHAR2, DATE or NUMBER. When using this code, the execution of my stored procedure fails because Oracle can't find out which method to use. (probably because JDBC lib doesn't map the timestamp to DATE column, as explained [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#08_01) )

The only way it worked was with:

```
callableStmt.setObject(6, new java.sql.Timestamp(attributeValue.getTime()), OracleTypes.DATE);
```

which seems to force the mapping between my Timestamp to DATE column in Oracle stored procedure while keeping the DD-MM-YYYY and HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Please also explain your code. A simple one-liner can be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a [`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

```
callableStmt.setTimestamp(6, new java.sql.Timestamp(attributeValue.getTime()));
```

Comment: My stored procedure input is defined as "i_value in date" so that doesnt work: when executing the stored procedure it says it can't find it (because of type mismatch)

Comment: According to [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#08_01], you may need the Oracle JDBC version that maps SQL DATES to java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: hmm, nice clues but I'm using 11.2.0.3 which should map it and still it doesn't... (I have 3 stored procedures with the same name and just a different type in the last IN parameter and I get the error that oracle matched 3 procedures to my input